# AngularJS, Apache, handling routes

Tags: angularjs, apache

I'm new to AngularJS, and after I played with `$routeProvider` I have fue things to ask...

Well I know AngularJS is used for single page applications, but what about url that is directly accessed for example:

**CASE 1:**

if someone will access `example.com` then he will click a link that will send him to: `example.com/article/title/`, well that will be ok because AngularJS will prevent client request to the server, so far no harm, **for now**.

**CASE 2:**

if I will send my article link to someone, and he will try to access `example.come/article/title/` well **404** is arrived.

**My question** is about the strategy to deal with that kind of behavior, I have some ideas but I'm not well familiar with AngularJS as I mentioned but:

1. I was thinking about rewrite rules via Apache rewrite engine, I ignore the rest of the url(`example.com/path` will become `example.com`), **but** that affect the relative links in my page, so I must switch to full links, for example (`example.com/js/main.js`).

The idea **is bad** I know it, but it allow AngularJS to take care of the urls at any case.

2. What seems(well I think) to be better strategy is using the Apache rewrite engine **again but** this time I will rewrite `example.come/article/title` to `example.com?title=articleTitle`, then I will check via my server side language(php) the value and pull out and print the article from the database to the page before it even get to AngularJS hands.

Now that approach kind of break the single page concept(no?), I have different opinions about this method.

**In summary**, I'm looking for the best way to handle url requests that outside the page, requests that AngularJS can't prevent.

**Edit:**

The problem is simple, when user click on a link from inside the website AngularJS will prevent the default action that is request the path from the server for example `example.com/article/title/` will look for the `title` folder that inside the `article` or more precisely the index for that folder.

Now if a friend send you a link that is directly a link that pointing to the a specific article for example `example.com/articl/title` there will be a server request to fetch the index for the `title` folder that inside the `article` folder under `example.com`.

Hope that makes more sense now.

Comment: Angular routes are like this: http://localhost:9000/#/repairs, that means the route is determined by the route id after the #.

Comment: @tomazahlin, Hi, I do know that but you don't expect me to use rewrite rules to add `#` before between `example.com` and `/article/title/` right, its an Idea, I was thinking about it but its a really bad one.

Comment: Hey, can you please explain CASE 1 and CASE 2 a little better? I do not fully understand what you are trying to achieve. Please tell me an example base URL of Angular application and what you are trying to do with the /article/title/.

Comment: @tomazahlin, Hi I did the edit.

Comment: I think I understand now. Only one thing - when angular prevents default action, what do you do with the url then or how do you get the data?

Comment: @tomazahlin, I'm using https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http service to fetch my data from the server.

Comment: Okay, you should definitely get rid of urls like example.com/article/title/ in the front-end if you ask me. I suggest you try to make them like example.com/#/article/title/, and with routeParams / stateParams (I do not know which provider you are using), construct the url to retrieve from server (you will do this in Article controller probably) and insert the data into the scope of the controller.

Comment: @tomazahlin I'm about to show post a solution using rewrite rule that uses `#`, it looks like the best solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I did found a solution in the form of Apache rewrite engine:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(/article/[a-z-]+/?)$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://example.com/#%1 [NE,R,L]
```

By using these rules I'm able to return the client `example.com/#/article/title`.

The next step is AngularJS will strip `#` leaving me with `example.com/article/title`.

No full path is needed, I may stay with my relative paths.